# Implementing thread-safe queue using one stack or more - java

Tags: java, multithreading, stack, queue

This is an interview question.
The first part was to implement a queue using one stack or more. This is a well-known question, and I gave an answer which is similar to method 2 [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-using-stacks/).

At the second part, I was asked if the code I wrote is thread-safe. My answer was that it isn't safe since multiple threads might modify the same object (first or second stack) at the same time.

Then I was asked if I can make this code thread-safe. What I suggested was to replace `Stack<Integer>` class with `ConcurrentLinkedDeque<Integer>`, which is a thread-safe stack.

The interviewer didn't seem to like the idea.
Do you have a better idea of how to make the code thread safe?

Comment: You need to synchronise the methods to avoid different threads operating on same stack

Comment: @AmidalaSivaKumar , I can use the keyword synchronized, but I think this solution is less elegant from what I suggested

Comment: Yes, it is less elegant but you are restricted to use only stacks. I feel it is the case to test to handle concurrency

Comment: java.util.Stack is thred-safe. so i think methods in your wrapper class(Queue) should be synchronized since it use two stacks .

Comment: @dush, First - why do you think Stack<E> is a thread-safe class? I don't see in Oracls Docs that it's written that Stack<E> is a thread-safe class. Second, can you please explain what concurrency problem we might have by using two stacks as you wrote?